# Do not save .pgw file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

When I capture the screen and save the file it also generates a .pwg file, I do not need it, only the .png

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("doc.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it:

```
import os
os.remove("doc.pwg")
```

Comment: and how do I prevent it from being generated?

Comment: Don't think you can https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a70bdf0387ea56e87d643b6a36c1e8610